# Disabling HighCharts labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and I want to turn off all the labels. I made my own graph that has its own title and data axes. How do I make the ones provided by Highcharts invisible?

At the moment, I just need to get rid of the y axis marks but I'm not certain how.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },

    title: {
        text: ' '
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rich',
        color: '#FF0000',
        data: []
    }, {
        name: 'Poor',
        data: []
    }]
});
}
```

Comment: `{tooltip:{enabled:false}}`?

Answer (score 6):

Highcharts has fabulous documentation with fiddle examples for most stuff: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/fnHzg/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    title : {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis: {

        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {

        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

To also turn off the yAxis and xAxis labels and tick marks:

```
xAxis: {

    title: {
        enabled: false
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tickLength: 0
},
yAxis: {

    title: {
        enabled: false
    },
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tickLength: 0
},
```

Comment: @seamlessTL In what way did it not work? What is still shown that you want to turn off?

Comment: Perfection. The last snippet was just what I needed. Another question, would you happen to know the process of applying padding to the left and right of the graph so that the initial and final points do not sit right on the edge? marginLeft, marginRight, spacingLeft, and spacingRight all seem to target the exterior of the graph - pushing the entire graph to one side.

Comment: xAxis.minPadding and xAxis.maxPadding.  Though they don't work with categories, but it doesn't look like you're using categories for any real purpose anyhow.  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding